# Mount Exchange 2010 EDB to Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange-2010, edb, exchange-2013

I know currently Exchange 2010 (with SP2) does not coexist with Exchange 2013.

If i was to install brand new Exchange 2013, new config, update schema etc, could i just simply mount the Exchange 2010 EDB?

Is this possible?

IF NOT, can i export the individual mailbox from Exchange 2010, and import to Exchange 2013?

Other info:

New domain installation (with existing domain name, Win2012), recreation of all users etc.

Comment: Why are you not doing a proper migration? If all the users are the same - there are AD migration tools and if you deploy 2013 alongside Exchange 2010 you can do live mailbox migrations...

Comment: @GeorgeHewitt AFAIK Microsoft have not yet released the patches for Exchange 2010 and Exchange 2007 that support co-existence with Exchange 2013. If you know differently please say so, because I'm waiting to migrate an Exchange 2007 org to 2013 as soon as they appear (http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2012/09/25/announcing-exchange-2010-service-pack-3.aspx).

Comment: @GeorgeHewitt the issue isn't AD migration, i can run powershell scripts. I can't deploy Exchange side my side, Exchange 2010 SP2 does not co-exist with 2013 as of yet.

Comment: Sorry you are of course correct. Obviously ahead of myself, aware that SP3 is on the way. My comments would obviously not help answer this question but it does seem a lot of effort just to get 2013 now rather than wait and migrate properly. But, that is not the focus of your question :-)

Comment: @RobM Exchange 2010 SP3 supporting co-existence has been released on Feb, 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to mount the databases from one instance of Exchange onto another one just like that. Actually to clarify, it *is* [possible](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd876873%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx) within the *same* Exchange org and might be required in some DR or reinstall scenarios, though I'd suggest it's not good practice as a general use thing.

As for migrating mailboxes, you can export them to PSTs then import them again. I'm not convinced this scales well for lots of users but it's there.

Grant yourself rights to do it (I'm assuming you're logged in as administrator) and then restart the exchange shell.

```
New-ManagementRoleAssignment –Role "Mailbox Import Export" –User Administrator
```

Ensure the target that you're exporting the mailboxes to has write permissions for the Exchange Trusted Subsystem group (important if you're doing this over a network to a share).

To export all mailboxes from an Exchange Organisation:

```
foreach ($i in (Get-Mailbox)) { New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $i -FilePath "e:\$($i.Alias).pst" }
```

These commands are a bit "approximate" as I don't have an Exchange 2010 server handy to double-check them with but they'll certainly get you into the ballpark.

As for what to do on Exchange 2013 once you've got the mailboxes, there's the `New-MailboxImportRequest` cmdlet. Not played with this on Exchange 2013 so I'll just point you at the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607310.aspx) for it. Needless to say you're basically importing the results of the earlier script into new mailboxes at this point..

Comment: Thanks @RobM I feared this was the case. I got about 300GB edb file, this is going to be one pain staking migration

Comment: @ColdT Yep. I'm not too happy about this myself, but I'm waiting for co-existence support. Not pretty though.

Comment: Would co-existence work in my scenario? In the most simplest explanation, i would have 2 seperate domains. Adding Exchange 2013 to the existing, updating schema etc, and then; would i able to mount DBs from one instance of Exchange 2013 to another brand new setup of Exchange 2013?

Comment: 2 separate domains or 2 separate forests? I've not tried it but move mailboxes between forests is supported (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee633491.aspx). Still think you'd need co-existence to make it work while migrating between different exchange levels, the sending and receiving servers need to understand one another's mailbox attributes right? If they're 2 domains in the same forest then the two domains will still be in the same exchange org right? So that won't help.

Comment: @coldt I mean "move-mailbox" specifically rather than trying to mount databases. I've done live migrations of several thousand users over a weekend before now, but that was a simple upgrade within an organisation, which helps. I've worked with Exchange for a long time and "mount databases from one server on another" has always been the wrong answer unless the question started with "my exchange server is horribly broken beyond repair and..."

Comment: sorry i did mean against two different forest. I will avoid 'mounting' EDBs altogether and look into move-mailbox/import/export options. Running out of time and ideas at this stage!

Comment: @coldt the mailbox export thing might be a pain, and will need a bit of testing before you leave it unsupervised obviously, but it does fundamentally work, if that's any comfort.

Answer (score 0):

You can not mount the database to new server simply, because all Exchange services are still on Exchange Server 2010. You can following this link to Migrate from Exchange 2010 to Exchange 2013: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj898583(v=exchg.150).aspx

Yes, you can export the mailboxes from Exchange 2010, and then import it to Exchange 2013. You can refer this link for the same: https://www.msb365.blog/?p=3899